# Where to discuss tech ideas on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Suppose that I have an idea with programming/cloud computing.

Since it's just an idea and there's nothing implemented yet, I can't discuss it on Stack Overflow because answers would be too opinionated and disoriented somehow.

Therefore, is there any section of the Stack Exchange network I should know about which would shed some light on some of the general steps and connect me with people who would like to discuss ideas not just to implement the idea into a real project?

Answer (score 5):

The key word in your question is "discuss".

There is no specific site that allows discussion type question - they just don't work with our style of Q&A.

You can always log onto chat and ask around in chat - things are much less formal there (try [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta) - if nothing else, they might know a different chat room that is more suitable).

Comment: Looks like I need to have 20 reputation to talk there, any other suggestions?

Comment: @Sam Get 20 rep - it's easy :)

Comment: @Sam - that's how the system works. And 20 reputation is not difficult (approved suggested edits will gain you 2 rep each, if you don't feel you can ask a good question or give a good answer).